# Не получается подключить composer

Tags: php, composer

Добрый день. Я пытаюсь подключить composer к сайту на modx revolution на хостинге beget. В статьях на хостинге я нашел описание как установить и установил. Он установился в папку в корне рядом с директорией самого сайта. На сколько я понял всё в порядке, даже получилось подключить одну библиотеку, но при попытке подключить файл autoload.php страница не грузится ив принципе к нему нет доступа. Подскажите пожалуйста где я был не прав?

Answer (score 0):

Смотря куда установился файл autoload.php.

Вы на хостинге может получаете доступ к корневой папке сайта, public_html, а к папке composer котрая лежит РЯДОМ с public_html, но доступа вы туда не имеете.

Comment: Там всё выглядит так: ~/папка сайта/public_html/файлы и рядом ~/vendor/autoload.php

Comment: тогда какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: Ну если просто пытаться подключиться то 500, но если проверять на существование файла, методом file_exists, то он просто не видит файл, как будто его нет.